# ArrayAdapter and listview Error

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I tried to setadapter for ther list view in the following code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    JSONArray jsonObject;
    ArrayList<String> arrayList= new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayList<String> articles= new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    public class Dwnl extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(strings[0]);

                URLConnection conn=null;
                conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                String contents="";

                InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
                int data =reader.read();
                int counter = 0;
                while (data!=-1) {    
                    contents+=(char)data;
                    data=reader.read();
                    //ounter++;
                }
                //contents = in.toString();
                jsonObject= new JSONArray(contents);
                //Log.i("Sire",String.valueOf(jsonObject.length()));
                arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                //arrayList.addAll((Collection<? extends String>) jsonObject);
                for(int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++) {

                    try {
                        //Log.i("URL", "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/" + jsonObject.get(i) + ".json?print=pretty");

                        String site = "";
                        site = "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/" + jsonObject.get(i) + ".json?print=pretty";
                        URL Second = new URL(site);
                        URLConnection newURlCon = (HttpURLConnection) Second.openConnection();
                        InputStream input = newURlCon.getInputStream();
                        InputStreamReader secondreader = new InputStreamReader(input);
                        int pos = secondreader.read();
                        String all = "";
                        while (pos != -1) {   
                            all += (char) pos;
                            pos = secondreader.read();
                        }
                        //Log.i("JSON",all);
                        JSONObject second = new JSONObject(all);
                        all = "";

                        articles.add(second.getString("title").toString());
                        Log.i("JSONSTR",articles.get(i));

                        //arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
                        e.printStackTrace(pw);
                        Log.i("Exp",sw.toString());
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Dwnl dwnl = new Dwnl();
        try {

            dwnl.execute("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty").get();
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,articles);
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
            e.printStackTrace(pw);
            Log.i("Exp",sw.toString());
        }   
    }
}
```

but this error always appears

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

I dont know what is null ther arraylist is of size 3 and there is nothing null at all

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NullPointerException is thrown by the `ListView`, not by the array.
In `onCreate` method you should call:

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
```

Replace `your_layout` with your `MainActivity` xml.

Answer (score 0):

Null is because you return null from .doInBackground (). You cannot set data to adapter from background thread, it will throw another exception. You must return result from .doInBackground and then handle it in .onPostExecute()

Comment: This isn't actually true. You can manipulate the list backing the adapter, you just can't call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` from a background thread.

Comment: Yes, and since it is commented out it is not the issue.